# Can't install Ubuntu 20.04 on ASUS Tuf a15 (ACPI?)

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel, 20.04, acpi

**TL;DR: Trying Ubuntu from pendrive works just fine. Installing it, don't. getting a black screen or lacking funcionality.**

I've tried installing ubuntu on my new laptop (Asus tuf A15 with nvidia rtx2060) about 23 times, so first, pretty frustrated.

When I boot the pendrive and check "Try Ubuntu", everything works fine. Wifi, trackpad, graphic drivers. But after installation it doesn't.

Had many troubles with nvidia drivers and getting kernel panics (which at this point I just gave up on nvidia drivers, goodbye Tensorflow). The closest thing to a working Ubuntu was:

After installing, before booting, I have to turn off the ACPI on the grub bootloder options (press `e` on Ubuntu and add `acpi=off`)

With this, I have no trackpad functionality or battery % showing, and some keyboard functions.
This is the `dmesg` output I could retrive when not working and login into some tty pressing fn+f2

Tried a a bunch of acpi options (acpi_osi=linux, acpi=stric, acpi=oldboot or whatever) and only acpi=off works

```
[    2.404697] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [IIA3] at bit offset/length 96/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (96 bits) (20190816/dsopcode-198)
[    2.404729] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [WMNB]
[    2.404733] Initialized Arguments for Method [WMNB]:  (3 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    2.404735]   Arg0:   000000008e11445c <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    2.404747]   Arg1:   00000000fce64be6 <Obj>           Integer 0000000054494E49
[    2.404753]   Arg2:   000000000ded1ebb <Obj>           Buffer(12) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[    2.404769] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.ATKD.WMNB due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    2.404854] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [IIA3] at bit offset/length 96/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (96 bits) (20190816/dsopcode-198)
[    2.404865] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [WMNB]
[    2.404868] Initialized Arguments for Method [WMNB]:  (3 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    2.404869]   Arg0:   000000000ded1ebb <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    2.404876]   Arg1:   00000000fce64be6 <Obj>           Integer 0000000043455053
[    2.404881]   Arg2:   000000008e11445c <Obj>           Buffer(12) 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 00
[    2.404895] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.ATKD.WMNB due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    2.404970] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [IIA3] at bit offset/length 96/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (96 bits) (20190816/dsopcode-198)
[    2.404981] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [WMNB]
[    2.404984] Initialized Arguments for Method [WMNB]:  (3 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    2.404985]   Arg0:   000000008e11445c <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    2.404991]   Arg1:   00000000fce64be6 <Obj>           Integer 000000004E554653
[    2.404997]   Arg2:   000000000ded1ebb <Obj>           Buffer(12) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[    2.405010] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.ATKD.WMNB due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    2.405030] asus-nb-wmi asus-nb-wmi: Detected ATK, not ASUSWMI, use DSTS
[    2.405034] asus-nb-wmi asus-nb-wmi: Detected ATK, enable event queue
[    2.405170] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [IIA3] at bit offset/length 96/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (96 bits) (20190816/dsopcode-198)
[    2.405180] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [WMNB]
[    2.405184] Initialized Arguments for Method [WMNB]:  (3 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    2.405185]   Arg0:   000000000ded1ebb <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    2.405191]   Arg1:   00000000fce64be6 <Obj>           Integer 0000000053564544
[    2.405197]   Arg2:   000000002a7c2a21 <Obj>           Buffer(12) 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 00
[    2.405210] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.ATKD.WMNB due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    2.405285] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [IIA3] at bit offset/length 96/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (96 bits) (20190816/dsopcode-198)
[    2.405295] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [WMNB]
[    2.405298] Initialized Arguments for Method [WMNB]:  (3 arguments defined for method invocation)
[    2.405300]   Arg0:   000000002a7c2a21 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[    2.405306]   Arg1:   00000000fce64be6 <Obj>           Integer 0000000053545344
[    2.405312]   Arg2:   000000000ded1ebb <Obj>           Buffer(12) 18 00 11 00 00 00 00 00
[    2.405325] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.ATKD.WMNB due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
```

Apparently this is a bad ACPI implementation compatible for win only blablabla. My BIOS is the latest one out there.

While trying ouy the `uname -a` output is
`Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**THE QUESTION:**
Why does it work while trying out but not after installation? I mean, the functionality *is there* and works, what is it breaking it?

I need this new notebook to work, don't make me work on windows please!! save a 10 years ubuntu user.

**EDIT:**
The only way to get it to a working state without ACPI, is installing in compatibility mode, installing 3rd party graphics and updates. Logging in Ubuntu (which glitches all over), getting into a tty, purge all `nvidia-*`  packages and then boot with the `acpi=off`. No trackpad, battery %, keyboard fn functions (like increase bightness).

There should be something that has to be installed to work...It can't work only in the "Try Ubuntu" phase...

Comment: Does live CD work correctly?

Comment: @AkibAzmain yes, it works fine (safe graphi option, not the normal one)

Comment: did you recently try to run Ubuntu on this laptop again? I have Asus TUF A15 FA506QR and I am tired of Windows on this machine, I was previously on Ubuntu, but this laptop came with preinstall Windows and I was lazy to install Ubuntu on it... now I am thinking if this is even possible to run Ubuntu on it or not...

Comment: @AlexanderCherednichenko No, didn't try, sorry, went full windows + wsl2 since this happened. I also miss using linux natively. The nearest I got a working env was with Manjaro distribution, but still some things were not working (IIRC, the function buttons and something else, I think bluetooth).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to pass the `nomodeset` parameter to the Linux kernel. If GRUB works and the menu appears, select the menu entry for Ubuntu (probably the first one) and press `e` . An editor screen will appear, then find the line starting with `linux` (just ignore whitespaces), then go to the end of the line and append `nomodeset` to the line. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot. It should boot properly. After it successfully boots, we need to make these changes permanent. To do that, open a terminal window and execute the following:

```bsh
gedit admin:///etc/default/grub
```

After the Text Editor window opens, it will prompt for your password (maybe twice), enter your password (not `root` password), you'll see the file contents. Find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` and add `nomodeset` to the value like this:

```
// Taken from my /etc/default/grub file
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

After you are done, save it and exit. Then execute the following in the terminal:

```bsh
sudo update-grub
```

You can restart your PC and everything will be fine. :)

Comment: tried that, didn't work. still getting a back screen and can't log in a tty also now adding both nomodeset and acpi=off doesn't work.

Comment: Oh I forgot, don't add `apci=off` .

Comment: tried it and getting a black screen. no access possibleto a tty.

Comment: @otrometalero Please add the full kernel parameter line to your question (from GRUB).

Comment: thanks for your help Akib, I gave up and will try Windows + WSL2, I removed ubuntu so can't get the full kernel parameter. I passed the `nomodeset` parameter but without the  `acpi=off` it didn't load, just getting a black screen (and couldn't get into a tty).

Comment: Also, tried linux mint with the safe graphic options and it happens too, needs the `acpi=off` option. Without the safe graphic option I ust get a black screen with both distros.

Comment: @otrometalero Are you sure? You'll miss many features.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. Connect your TV or another monitor via HDMI cable and see if the picture goes there while you are having a black screen. If it does then you can go to display settings and activate your main monitor.