# No option for ubuntu install

Tags: boot, grub2

While dual booting ubuntu  through usb drive after making partitions . When I restarted my pc and selected bootable usb drive I didn't get option of install Ubuntu .it shows acpi error when I choose Ubuntu option I also scanned my memory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Ubuntu 20.04 on ASUS Tuf a15 (ACPI?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267811/cant-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-asus-tuf-a15-acpi)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)