# Can't install Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, acpi

I've tried dual booting and installing Ubuntu 20.04 with the recommended methods on the internet using the latest Rufus with GPT (my system is UEFI), disabling Secure Boot, Fast boot, using "nomodeset" in the Grub bootloader (I have a AMD processor HP ENVY), but it always stops at this error screen while booting.

[image]

This black screen appears while I boot Ubuntu from my USB drive, and it hangs it here, nothing afterwards.

I could install Ubuntu in VirtualBox on my laptop, but it has been weeks I've been trying to install it from my 16GB USB stick, but I had no success.

Comment: Are you saying A) you can't install it on the USB or B) you have installed it on the USB and it won't boot or C) you have installed it on your laptop hard drive from a USB or D) you haven't installed it at all, the install USB won't boot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Ubuntu 20.04 on ASUS Tuf a15 (ACPI?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267811/cant-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-asus-tuf-a15-acpi)

Comment: I can install it on USB. But it won't boot, rather takes me to the black screen I mentioned. I tried editing the grub with "nomodeset", "amdgpu.modeset=0", "nosplash". I also updated my Bios from the official HP's site. While trying amdgpu.modeset=0, it goes further until "Begin: init/..." But not further. There is no any problem while installing and opening it on VirtualBox.

Comment: @karel This is not a duplicate of the question you mentioned, because OP tried "nomodset".

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I didn't want to link to the wild `nomodeset` answer. I wanted to link to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=strict"` because of the error message on the question's screen photo.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that the Live USB is not properly formatted. Try using rufus with the dd option.

Comment: I've tried installing the iso file directly on my C: using Unetbootin as well. Even after it is installed, and I load Ubuntu from the bios, it doesn't open. I have tried doing it with the dd option (with MBR, GPT) with not just Ubuntu but also with Linux Mint, Elementary OS, FydeOS, Lubuntu, Manjaro, and others. Yet, it doesn't go further than the same boot screem I uploaded. I just don't want to use Windows 10.