# RTL8822CE wireless adapter doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, asus, adapter

I just bought a asus tuf gaming a15 and wanted to install ubuntu 18.04 (not 20.04 because some programs like tensorrt is not yet supported there). I used a bootable usb to install and after installing i could not boot because of this issue [Can't install Ubuntu 20.04 on ASUS Tuf a15 (ACPI?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267811/cant-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-asus-tuf-a15-acpi)  so following the recommended answers (GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset") i manage to boot. But then i realised that while wifi seems to working it cannot find any networks around.

```
$ifconfig
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::53fc:d382:186c:5e32  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:7c:3f:1b:5e:22  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 55782  bytes 69075165 (69.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 27388  bytes 2805436 (2.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2433  bytes 240013 (240.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2433  bytes 240013 (240.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
$wfconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

```
$lshw -C netowork
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 3c:7c:3f:1b:5e:22
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:51 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc904000-fc904fff memory:fc900000-fc903fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 80:30:49:d2:17:d3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-64-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:68 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fc800000-fc80ffff
```

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c822]
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0810]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
dmesg | grep rtw
[    2.898620] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    2.898846] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtw88/rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin failed with error -2
[    2.898850] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to request firmware
[    2.905431] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: Firmware version 5.0.0, H2C version 14
[    3.001512] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    3.229403] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[    3.239120] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[    3.239953] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   13.096755] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   13.097719] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   23.098690] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   23.099604] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   33.100008] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   33.101058] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   43.103821] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   43.105017] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   53.103730] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
[   53.104875] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to wait firmware completion
```

i dont think its adapter's problem as windows 10 seems find well the adapter. Its first time i find such a problem so i dont know what do so please if someone had never dealed with such a bug inform me.

(I can connect to internet with ethernet that works fine)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 done, seems that it is not blocked by hard or soft.

Comment: It is not blocked, but the driver doesn't support this adapter. You need to install another.

Comment: Please also add output of `dmesg | grep rtw`.

Comment: @Pilot6 i have no much experience on Ubuntu how can i install another, and how to find which is suitable?

Comment: I am looking into it. Hold on.

Comment: You need firmware. I am looking how it is easier to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `linux-firmware` in Ubuntu 18.04 repository doesn't contain `rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin` file. In 20.04 it is already added.

You can get it this way. Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install git
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp linux-firmware/rtw88/rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin /lib/firmware/rtw88
```

Reboot, and Wi-Fi should work.

You can delete the `linux-firmware` directory if you like. It is not needed after you install the firmware.

Comment: You really saved my day. Thank you!!!

Comment: save my day man! Thank you